# Inject different type of class using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm new to dependency injection. I got a doubt while reading about Ninject.

In Ninject wiki I saw an basic example for Dependency Injection. From that my doubt arises.

This is the [link](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-By-Hand).

```
class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon weapon;
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public void Attack(string target)
    {
        this.weapon.Hit(target);
    }
}
class Shuriken : IWeapon
{
    public void Hit(string target)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pierced {0}'s armor", target);
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        var warrior1 = new Samurai(new Shuriken());
        var warrior2 = new Samurai(new Sword());
        warrior1.Attack("the evildoers");
        warrior2.Attack("the evildoers");
    }
}
```

Below is the statement mentioned in that link.

> "When classes are tightly coupled, they cannot be interchanged without altering their implementation. In order to avoid tightly coupling classes, we can use interfaces to provide a level of indirection."

If I want to create new class called Dress and inject to Samurai class. That time also I need to rewrite Samurai class know like below

```
class Samurai
{
    readonly IWeapon weapon;
    readonly IDress dress
    public Samurai(IWeapon weapon, IDress dress)
    {
        this.weapon = weapon;
        this.dress = dress;
    }

    public void Attack(string target)
    {
        this.weapon.Hit(target);
    }

     public void Wear(){


     }
}
```

Or else do I have any other option???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what your question has to do with dependency injection or IoC, but your other option to altering the definition of of `Samurai` is to extend it into a new class, e.g.

```
public ClothedSamurai : Samurai
{
    readonly IDress dress;
    public ClothedSamurai(IWeapon weapon, IDress dress) : base(weapon)
    {
        this.dress = dress;
    }    

    public void Wear()
    {
        //whatever this does
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Preston Guillot